# How to apply filled mask to an audio spectrum layer?

Tags: color, shapes, path, mask, adobe-after-effects

Sorry if the question may appear confusing, I will try to explain as clearly as possible. I have created an audio spectrum layer and I'm trying to apply a filled mask to it. See first image: I drew a shape with a pen tool and my goal is to apply a fill effect only to audio spectrum.

[image]

Once I fill that mask with a desired color, I fill the whole mask. How can I fill only to audio spectrum layer?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Preserve Underlying Transparency" option on an overlay layer; this will however only work if there is nothing else behind the layers, since the option derives the transparency from the layers below (make sure "Composite On Original" *isn't* checked on your audio spectrum). You can get around that by pre-comping only those layers if needs be.

Take these two layers, a solid layer with an audio spectrum effect, and a shape layer:

[image]

Hitting the box under "T" will enable the "Preserve Underlying Transparency" option (you may need to hit the "Toggle Switches / Modes" button to show the option):

[image]

You can read more in the help docs here:

- [**Use alpha channels, masks, and mattes in After Effects - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/alpha-channels-masks-mattes.html#preserve_underlying_transparency_during_compositing)

Comment: Or more simple solution is to create two audio spectrum layers, precompose the red one and apply mask on to it. I don't know how I didn't thought about that. I really appreciate your answer though.